# Fragment / Toolbar from fragment is shown at the wrong position

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, kotlin, toolbar

I started to use a toolbar instead of an ActionBar. The toolbar is set in each layout. But as you can see in the picture, the fragment with the toolbar does not start directly below the statusbar. Moreover the toolbar crashes with the text from grid layout.

[image]

Here is the code of activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:elevation="0.1dp"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_colors"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the code of the fragment_finder.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:targetApi="21"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Toolbar Title" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="7" >

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:columnCount="3"
            android:rowCount="1"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins" >

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_country"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/pacifico"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_finder"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/pacifico"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_age"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/pacifico"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </GridLayout>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:elevation="10dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profileview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ex1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:columnCount="3"
            android:rowCount="1"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/schlecht"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/schlecht"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/hot"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/hot"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/gut"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/gut"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        </GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I hope anybody can help me with this problem.

With kind regards
Jeremy

Comment: Remove below line from activity_main
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"

Comment: Thank you. Now the Toolbar is on the right place but the toolbar an the grid-layout are still crashing into each other.

Comment: Give 
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
to your relative layout in fragment_finder

Comment: your welcome @Jeremy Brehe. You can upvote my answer if your problem is solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer to the first part:
Remove below line from activity_main

```
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Add line to Relative layout in fragment_finder

```
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use toolbar you can assign as a actionbar so, no need to add padding in layout you can use below code to set toolbar as a actionbar

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```